# Don't show reviews I skipped in my history

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, review-queues, profile-page

Before today, and the new review queue, I had 7 pages of [total documentation activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6083675/laurel?tab=documentation&sort=all). That was only 12 hours ago.

I now have **OVER TWENTY** pages.

Here's why:

> [image]

WAIT! Before you reach for your flags, let me explain: I was only button mashing the Skip button. [There is no shame in mashing Skip!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/6083675)

By using Skip, then the back button several times in a row, you can even review the same thing five times in a row:

> [image]

Please make it stop. I can't find anything I actually reviewed, and I need to follow up on some of my plagiarism reviews.

This only has been happening for Documentation reviews after the new queue. [The other queues don't act like that](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6083675/laurel?tab=activity&sort=reviews), hence I feel it is a bug.

Comment: @RobertLongson Wrong page. This is in the _profile_ under documentation tab (http://stackoverflow.com/users/2153758/bwoebi?tab=documentation). On http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/history?userId=2153758 there's that checkbox, yes. But not in the profile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I forgot about that user profile tab when implementing "skip" results.

A fix will be pushed out shortly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can see your review history for proposed changes in Documentation at the [history tab](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/history?userId=6083675&skipped=false). Unchecking the "show skipped reviews" checkbox at the bottom will exclude the skipped reviews from the results.

Unfortunately there's currently no way to filter the Documentation activity on the user profile.

Comment: The bug is that this started with the new queue, and it does not happen for my main review tab. But at least I can use that other page for now.