# A way for an Expert to be treated as "normal" in the Documentation review workflow

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I'm a gold badge holder for the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag which means that my Documentation edits go through without any approvals, and my review votes have final force.

Most of the time this is fine.  Sometimes I actually want to be NOT treated as being "special".

- Sometimes I want my edits to go through a review ... because getting a consensus is good.
- Sometimes I want my approval votes to be part of a consensus building process.

I'm not sure how this would be implemented, but one idea would be extra "submit" options and extra approve / reject options for people with "expert" status for a tag / book.

Comment: Doubtful this will happen, because such a thing (allow the user to choose whether to use their powers) has been suggested for the main site for moderators and Mjolnir-wielders and declined.

Comment: I think you could have a second account and use that for the edits you want not to use your special powers. You can also vote with that account when all you want is consensus building. Just make sure your two accounts don't interact (like account A voting on account B answers) and you should be good.

Comment: @Kaiido I don't think there's a path to getting tag badges via documentation votes and edits yet ;)

Comment: @BenVoigt  - Hopefully, this request will be considered on its merits.  In particular, what I am talking about here is consensus within an (often) really small community of people active in a given Documentation tag.  On the general site, the community is much larger, and simply opting out of making a decision is a more viable approach.

Comment: With respect, I think this is a 'have your cake and eat it, too' situation, that doesn't take the holistic view of Docs. That is to say, it is a collaborative effort, and from what I have seen, the developers really want the review process to include edits by other users (*ex post facto*, rather than during the traditional review queue process).

Comment: @TylerH - Are you saying that you think that there should be no special status for silver / gold tag people?  I could probably live with that.  However, the developers clearly had a reason for implementing the special status stuff ... too.

Comment: @StephenC No, I'm saying a special status for silver / gold tag people *implies* that you get certain privileges. The flip side is that you give up other privileges as well. Just as a US President gives up the comfort of his private life to serve in office, so does a gold badge user on SO give up the comfort of a peer review when submitting a change. The system is designed upon *community*-based trust, so to unilaterally undermine/supersede the *community's* trust In you would kind of go against the design, however noble the intentions.

Comment: @StephenC While I personally wouldn't mind that feature (let us check a box to require a review from other gold / silver badge users rather than having it automatically be approved), my guess is that the developers would consider that feature to be one that falls under the popular design umbrella of "too many choices/options is bad and harmful".

Answer (score 15):

Considering [how review works right now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334877/limit-the-docs-review-votes-for-lower-rep-users), a low rep user with zero experience in the technology and zero score in the tag can "review" a dozen of major changes within a minute, and the system considers that acceptable. Basically, if it doesn't look like outright spam, it'll be accepted. I've seen a badly formatted question being approved by a user.

So, while in general I agree with your proposal, because as an owner of a silver badge I'm still not always absolutely sure about my changes, this is not how review system works right now, it doesn't look like something is being done in that area, so your proposal just won't work as intended.

Comment: You are correct.  I was implicitly assuming that the general problem with bad Documentation reviews will be solved separately.