# An "I'm done" button for all review queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

There has been more than a few times, I've been reviewing and I've accidentally hit a button. Seeing as there currently is no way to undo votes, etc., after you've moved to the next review.

I propose we implement an <kbd>I'm done</kbd> button for all review queues.

Many people may say "an additional I'm done button would be very obtrusive".

Review's are not meant to be done quickly; they are meant to be done accurately.
Many people zoom through reviews as quick as possible.

*This button would slow them down forcing the people who are going through them quickly to think about the question for an extra second, and give them a chance to catch any mistakes they've made.*

Comment: You are not always alone when reviewing, for the first post queue (if i'am not mistaken), peoples are voting until there is a certain number of same answers wich determine the post's state. In this case what's the matter with a "I'am done button", since i doubt everyone will click the wrong button, 1 on 5 is not a big deal. Not even mentioning the fact that it's your job to make sure you are not missclicking, and if that happens a lot, maybe you should learn from it and slow yourself down a bit ?

Answer (score 6):

I'm very familiar with the Close Vote queue, so that's the only one I'll be talking about.

You enter the queue. The system presents you with a post and says "some person flagged or voted to close this post. What do you want to do?"

You have four options:

1. You disagree, and think it should be left open as-is. <kbd>Leave Open</kbd>
2. You agree, and go through the dialog menu to close it. <kbd>Close</kbd>
3. You think some edits you can make allows the post to stay open. <kbd>Edit</kbd>
4. You have no idea. <kbd>Skip</kbd>

Let's first talk about how it's possible to *accidentally* press the wrong option.

Pressing <kbd>Close</kbd> or <kbd>Edit</kbd> presents you with additional steps that you need to perform, along with a final "OK" button, before you can complete the review. This is the "I'm Done" functionality you're looking for.

If you press <kbd>Skip</kbd>, just hit the back button in your browser to get a chance to re-review the item.

<kbd>Leave Open</kbd> is the only option that instantly terminates your interaction with the review and provides no conformation. As long as the review wasn't an audit you won't incur any penalty. Press the back button in the browser and manually apply a close vote to the post.

In addition, there is a ~2 second delay before the first three option buttons are enabled when the page loads, helping accidental double-clicks.

Will adding an addition "submit" button limit or prevent this behavior?

I do not think so. There is only 1 option you can accidentally press that has an instant effect, and that option is used only [14% of the time](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/846886/1045519/).

---

Of course, some people aren't in the business of devoting a lot of time to reviewing each post with the attention it deserves.

There are various levels of robo-reviews:

What I'll call "Level 1 RRs" are people who skim through a post without grasping the true meaning of what is written, then casting judgement based on their feelings of the tone of the text. I'm sure we've all done this at some point, but these people do it regularly.

Level 2 RRs typicly have the goal to complete their 40 reviews as fast as possible, which means either hitting <kbd>Leave Open</kbd> (it's the fastest option) or using the same close reason repeatedly without truly consulting with the post's content. These people probably have understood that all CV audits can be passed by pressing the <kbd>Edit</kbd>, *even if you don't actually edit the post.*

Level 3 RRs are essentially bots. The HTML of the review page actually tells you if the review item is an audit or not, and userscript authors can pick up on that. They can automate the whole process.

Will adding an addition "submit" button limit or prevent this behavior?

It might limit Level 1's, but it will not stop anyone else. If you've got to the point where you're intentionally rushing through the system, simply adding a small speed bump won't do much. There are [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits) [discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334387/robo-and-superficial-reviewing-on-documentation) already on how to reduce robo-reviews.